# Getting the following error: 13279:can't find self in the replset config when configuring replica sets

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am configuring a 3 node mongodb replica set on linux. I am using the following config

```
fork = true
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27017
verbose = true
dbpath =  /opt/mongoDB/data/db
logpath = /opt/mongoDB/log/mongod.log
logappend = true
journal = true
replSet = rs1
keyFile = /opt/mongoDB/mongodb/bin/conf/keyfile
```

to start the server. I started the server and when I run connected to the server using mongo command line tool.

When I did `rs.initiate()` I get

```
{
    "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
    "me" : "host-ip:27017",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "couldn't initiate : can't find self in the replset config"
}
```

I tried providing the cfg to `initiate()` and still get the same error.

This is what shows up in the log file.

```
Mon Oct 14 13:27:33.218 [rsStart] replSet info no seed hosts were specified on the --replSet command line
Mon Oct 14 13:27:34.118 [conn1] run command admin.$cmd { replSetInitiate: { _id: "rs1", members: [ { _id: 0.0, host: "host-ip:27017" } ] } }
Mon Oct 14 13:27:34.118 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate admin command received from client
Mon Oct 14 13:27:34.118 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate config object parses ok, 1 members specified
Mon Oct 14 13:27:34.118 [conn1] getallIPs("host-ip"): [ip address]
Mon Oct 14 13:27:34.118 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Mon Oct 14 13:27:34.118 [conn1] User Assertion: 13279:can't find self in the replset config
Mon Oct 14 13:27:34.119 [conn1] replSet replSetInitiate exception: can't find self in the replset config
Mon Oct 14 13:27:34.119 [conn1] command admin.$cmd command: { replSetInitiate: { _id: "rs1", members: [ { _id: 0.0, host: "host-ip:27017" } ] } } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) W:230 reslen:107 1ms
```

When should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Note: I checked my /etc/hosts file and there is an entry for localhost and this specific server ip address with the name .

Answer (score 23):

I could not initiate Replica Set of MongoDB on CentOS machine.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set

mongodb replset

```
rs.initiate()


{
    "errmsg":"couldn't initiate : can't find self in the replset config on port 27011"
}
```

Then I just used JSON object parameter to `rs.initiate(rsconfig)`

```
var rsconfig = {"_id":"rs1","members":[{"_id":1,"host":"127.0.0.1:27011"}]}
```

then rs.add(..) or just all at once

```
var rsconfig = {"_id":"rs1","members":[{"_id":1,"host":"127.0.0.1:27011"},{"_id":2,"host":"127.0.0.1:27012"},{"_id":3,"host":"127.0.0.1:27013"}]}
```

check with `print(JSON.stringify(rsconfig))` then

```
rs.initiate(rsconfig)
```

after several seconds check

```
rs.status()
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Don't set `127.0.0.1` to `bind_ip`, change the `bind_ip` to the machine's name or ip address (such as `192.168.0.1`).

Comment: sure, local IP addresses are for test environment only.

Comment: 0.0.0.0, nor commenting out worked.  At least in 2.6